# Young adult - world is in negative/dark

Tags: story-identification

I read this 20 or more years ago. It had something to do with young people (maybe boys, girls or both) being lured into a world where everything was darkness, like a negative world. The one thing I remember clearly about it is that light would destroy things, and one child (trying to get out was in a classroom watching a filmstrip) tried to knock over the projector to start a fire, but it only created black flames.

I don't even remember if it was a book or a story, but I do remember it was aimed at young adults. I want to say it was a paperback book.

Answer (score 5):

This is "The Haunted School", a Goosebumps book. A photographer traps an entire class in a negative black-and-white world via his camera, and the protaganist accidentally stumbles in a different way. The only disparity I see with your description is that it's color, not light, that lets you escape - they set a fire on purpose hoping the flames would still be colored, but they weren't.

Answer (score 1):

Might be Madeleine L'Engle's [A Wrinkle in Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wrinkle_in_Time), in which the teenish protagonists visit worlds under domination of 'the darkness'.

Comment: If the description given in the question is correct, it's definitely not *A Wrinkle in Time*.

Comment: I've been wrong before!