# World where it rains every day of the year except one?

Tags: story-identification, ray-bradbury

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the name & author of this short story that takes place off planet involving sun & rain?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1032/what-is-the-name-author-of-this-short-story-that-takes-place-off-planet-involv)

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13075/young-adult-world-is-in-negative-dark) reminded me of a story that I read (plus saw a short movie about) when I was little. I think I was in elementary or jr. high school still. It was about a world where the sun only shone for one day of the year, I think. Maybe it was one day out of 7 years! The story focused on school kids. They lived in a grey world, but it was not evil as the question linked above implies, more like sad and depressing...

In the film, I have a clear image of a young child reaching out and holding a sunbeam in their hand, perhaps for the first time in their life.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are probably thinking of [All summer in a Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_summer_in_a_day) by Ray Bradbury.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_summer_in_a_day#Television_episode) or [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0195517/combined) for the info on the television episode.

I haven't read it for years, but, as I recall, the main character had moved from Earth, and her classmates had been born on Venus.  She claimed to recall the Sun.  Since the last time it had been visible on Venus, they had been about 2 years old (and subsequently not able to recall it), they became angry with her, and locked  her in a closet.  The sun came out, they went and enjoyed it, only later remembering that they had left her in the closet, causing her to miss the rare sunlight.

Comment: Yes! That's it! How wonderful and awful. One hour every seven years. I'm so glad our teacher chose to study it. Such powerful lessons in a tiny story.