# School kids go through a secret entrance and get trapped in a grey classroom

Tags: story-identification

What I could remember is that a school had a history of an entire class going missing. Some kids found a secret entrance in the school (I think it was an elevator that went sideways instead of up and down) that lead to a sealed-off classroom where they found the missing class and teacher.

The entire room plus the students and teacher were gray. The longer the new kids stayed the more they turned gray too. They were going to be forever trapped in that gray room with the missing kids but one girl realized her red lipstick had not turned gray yet and they were able to draw a door to escape.

Comment: Do you remember if this was a short story, a novel or something else?  Also, we don't know when you were a teen, please indicate a range of years that you may have read this in.

Comment: This sounds familiar. My first thought was Miss Zarves and the [19th story](https://wayside-school.fandom.com/wiki/Nineteenth_story) in the *Wayside Schools* stories, but looking a bit closer, it doesn't match.

Comment: I think I've found it. You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 8):

R.L. Stines's *[The Haunted School](https://goosebumpsfanon.fandom.com/wiki/The_Haunted_School)*

> On the night of the dance, Tommy and his friend Benjamin "Ben" Jackson need to fix a banner. While searching for needed materials, they find an elevator that goes sideways and transports them to a classroom in black and white world, a place where everything is in gray scale (black and white). Here they meet Seth Cortez and his friends, Eddie, Mona, Eloise, and Mary who became a few of the members of the Missing Class of 1947 who have not aged even after all that time. Seth tells them the story of how a photographer named Mr. Chameleon sent them to this colorless world in a "crack" with his camera, during the class photo. Everyone transported to this world gradually loses their colors.

...

> Thalia explained to her friends how she opened her tube of lipstick one day and got excited after discovering that it still had color. She hadn't seen colors in so long, she tried to draw on the wall to make colorful pictures. But when her lipstick touched the wall, it made an exit into the real world. Thalia immediately went through it without thinking and the hole instantly closed, before she could go back for the others. She had tried to make another hole but the lipstick was only ordinary in the real world.

Found with a search for `classroom elevator sideways "turning grey"`

Comment: Also an unaccepted answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13075/young-adult-world-is-in-negative-dark/39204#39204, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83557/story-about-students-stuck-in-a-black-and-white-universe/83583#83583 (has a question duped to it), and https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/2966/481